# Bi-annual Salesforce MVP Nominations are Open - Winter '17

Tags: discussion, mvp

**Public service announcement:**

The [MVP nominations](https://www.salesforce.com/mvp/nominations.jsp) are open from now until January 13th, 2017 at 5:00 p.m. PST.

Feel free to nominate <strike>(or renominate)</strike> those who have made an exceptional contribution to the SFSE community. That could be [users](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/users?tab=Reputation&filter=year) or [moderators](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/users?tab=moderators) or anyone else who has helped you on your way.

See also: [Top 5 Things to Know About How We Choose Our MVPs](https://www.salesforce.com/blog/2016/02/how-we-choose-salesforce-mvps.html)

Comment: Should we renominate existing MVP as well as put forward new people or do Salesforce deal with that by reviewing their activity?

Comment: @DaveHumm Existing MVPs go through a separate renewal process so technically don't need to be renominated.

Comment: thanks for the clarification. I'll have to have a look to see if anyone here that has been putting in good content for the last year isn't an MVP already.

Comment: I'm sure there are a few! We have an awesome community going.

Comment: Why isn't @AdrianLarson MVP? I wonder why. I guess I will nominate him. :)

Comment: I have nominated Adrian

Comment: AdrianLarson would be my vote as well.....

Comment: Me too! I support @AdrianLarson.

Comment: I'm not sure I engage enough people to merit voting for someone?  I've had some recent contributions to my questions that have been helpful, such as by cloud-ninja - and there's always BobBuzzard, though I don't think I've engaged with him in the past few months.

Comment: @AMM It doesn't necessarily need to be someone who's engaged with you directly, rather someone who you've noticed blatantly demonstrates knowledge and dedication to the community. Keir is already an MVP (not sure if you have to renominate although I doubt Keir's MVP status is in any danger). Of course, you can always abstain! :)

Comment: @AdrianLarson is the next MVP :)

Comment: Keir is still active in the London Developer Group, blogs and the Speaker Academy so no problem for him to retain MVP status.

Comment: @AdrianLarson You have my vote :-)

Comment: @AdrianLarson got my vote too!

Answer (score 15):

For the record, often it seems that even outstanding SFSE contributors aren't regarded as MVP material by Salesforce if they don't participate anywhere other than SFSE. It used to be that SFSE didn't really count, but I think we've turned a corner on that these days and it's being recognised for the awesome channel it is.

Existing MVPs get to provide feedback on nominations, and since @santanu has nominated Adrian already I can definitely say he'll be getting great feedback from me :P

Comment: SFSE has helped in recognizing many awesome contributors. @sfdcfox is the best example from the SFSE side. There are few more.

Comment: @Ashwani, you too